# Is the main site down?

Tags: bug

I cannot access the main site, but I can access this meta site. Is the main site down? The stackexchange status on twitter does not mention anything.

Comment: Not working for me either.

Comment: Only the front page seems to be down. Everything else, such as browsing tags, works for me.

Comment: Only the [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended) and [interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tabs are down. [The](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) [tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) the front page are still functioning.

Comment: It's working again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just like what Antony said, only the recommended and interesting tabs are down. The other tabs are still functioning.

**Update:**

After almost 15 minutes, it's working again! :) What I'm really worried is the disturbing random images that I've seen. Maybe that's the real way of fixing StackOverflow? :)

[image]

Comment: I like the unicorn.